# Performance Python Windows vs. Ubuntu

Tags: performance, python-2.7

The following Script takes 20 sec.  on a Notebook with Windows 7 (32-bit) and an Intel I5 Processor the mean value for each QR was about 2.3 sec.

But on my new PC with an AMD FX-8320 8x 3.5GHz and Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) it takes about 27 seconds and about 3.0 seconds for each QR. I use Python 2.7.6.

I'm a little bit confused about that.

```
arr = np.random.rand(2000,2000)
duration = []

for i in range(1,10):
    start = time.time()
    x = linalg.qr(arr)
    stop = time.time()
    duration += [stop-start]

print "Mean: %f" %np.mean(duration)    
print "Total: %f" %np.sum(duration)
```

Comment: While possibly not relevant, the "Intel i5" has existed for five years, and might be either an obsolete processor, or the latest model with more than twice the performance of its ancestor.

Comment: It'd also be helpful to remove one variable - compare CPUs, or operating systems, not both.

Comment: I don't want to compare something. There is a small script which runs 50% faster on a notebook with a single processor than on a desktop with an octa core. And I'd like to know how that can be.

Comment: Couldn't tell you, but the pedant in me compels me to tell you that your octocore is a single processor. That is slower than some i5s, much slower when using only a single core. And that not all code can take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The script will probably use only one core.